# Rails no route matches update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

```
# Here's the error I am getting when trying to load my partial:
`ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"queries"}:`


# Here's the form I am trying to load within a partial on the `queries/1/edit` page:
`<%= form_for @query, url: {action: 'update'}, method: :put do |f| %>`


# Here's my controller:
def update
  @query = Query.find(params[:query])
  if @query.update(query_params)
    redirect_to queries_path, notice: 'Saved query successfully!'
  else
    redirect_to edit_query_path, alert: @query.errors.full_messages
  end
end


# Route:
resources :queries
```

I've tried passing in `@query => 1` and `@query => Query.find_by_id(1)` and `@query => Query.find(params[:query_id])` to the partial, but still get the "no route matches update" error.

I've tried `<%= form_for(@query) do |f| %>` instead of the url way, but get this error `QueriesController#MY_PARTIAL is missing a template for this request format and variant.`

Please help me get unstuck =) `Rails 5.0.1, ruby 2.3.0p0`

Comment: `<%= form_for @query do |f| %>` is usually enough if everything is set up correctly in your routes.

Comment: @Iceman yes, i was surprised when that didn't work. i am submitting the `form_for` from a route deep in a concern file that is properly linked to the controller, so i thought more specification might be in order?

Comment: How are you rendering this partial?

Comment: `$("#query-builder").hide().html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'queries/layer_5') %>").fadeIn(500);` This js is triggered by submitting a form_tag

Comment: What's the name of the file that contains this? It might be that Rails doesn't find it.

Comment: Hmm. It should be finding it okay because I load layers 1-4 the exact same way. `layer_4_.js.erb` runs that js when `form_tag :layer_4` submits

Comment: Well, I don't think the form is the issue, there is some naming mismatch somewhere it seems.

Comment: So I looked at the `form_for` params again and to my surprise, `id: "1"` was being passed so I changed the controller to `def update @query = Query.find_by_id(params[:id])`

Comment: @Iceman solved/ edited. thanks for the help!

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax If you were able to solve the problem by yourself, please write it at the answer part and accept that answer. That is more understandable then editing it into question.

Comment: @infiniteRefactor ah, it used to not let me post an answer on the same day that i asked the question

Answer (score 1):

So I looked at the `form_for` params again and, to my surprise, I saw that `id: "1"` was being passed. Thus, I changed the controller to

```
def update 
  @query = Query.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

This now works with `<%= form_for(@query) %>`

Comment: You can do just `Query.find(params[:id])`, id is used by default